# 3 level nested object to cascade drop downs with jQuery - 3rd level not working

Tags: jquery

I'm creating cascading drop down list from 3 level nested object. I'm unable to make 3rd level work, my attempt is commented inside at the end.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var carsdata = {
    "ALFA ROMEO": {
      "147": ["1,6 TS", "1,9 JTD", "1,9 JTD 16V MULTIJET", "1,9 JTD 120", "2,0 TS"],
      "156": ["1,9 JTD", "1,9 JTD 16V MULTIJET", "2,4 JTD"],
      "159": ["1,9 JTDM", "2,4 JTDM"],
      "159 SW": ["1,9 JTDM", "2,4 JTDM"],
      "166": ["2,0 TWIN SPARK 16V", "2,4 JTD", "2,0 TS"],
      "GIULIA": ["2,9 V6 BI-TURBO", "2,2 JTD", "2,2 JTDM"],
      "GIULIETTA": ["1,6 D. N. A", "2,0 D. N. A", "1,6", "2,0 TCT", "1,4 TB 16V D. N. A", "2,0", "1,6 MULTIJET", "1,4 TB"],
      "GT": ["1,9 JTD M-JET"],
      "GTV": ["2,0 TWIN SPARK 16V"],
      "MITO": ["1,6 JTDM", "1,4 T-JET", "1,4 TB", "1,3 JTDM", "1,4", "1,4 T-JET SPORT", "1,3"],
      "STELVIO": ["2,2 DIESEL", "2,0 TURBO"]
    },
    "AUDI": {
      "80": ["1,9 TDI", "2.0", "1,6"],
      "A1": ["1,6 TDI", "1,0 TFSI", "2,0 TDI", "1,4 TFSI", "1,2 TFSI", "1,6 TDI S-TRONIC", "1,4 TDI"],
      "A2": ["1,4 TDI", "1,4"],
      "A3": ["2,0 TDI", "1,6 TDI SPORT", "1,6 TDI", "1,9 TDI", "1,6", "1,6 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,0 TDI SPORT S-TRONIC", "1,8 TFSI", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "1,2 TFSI", "1,8", "1.6 TDI", "1,4 TFSI", "2,0 TDI SPORT", "35 TDI", "2,0 FSI", "1", "1,8 T", "30 TDI", "35 TFSI", "A3 LIMOUSINE 1,6 TDI S TRONIC", "1,0 TFSI"],
      "A3 CABRIO": ["1,6 TDI", "2,0 TDI", "1,9 TDI", "1,8 TFSI"],
      "A3 COUPE": ["1.6 TDI", "1,6", "2.0 TDI"],
      "A4": ["2,0 TDI SPORT", "2,0 TDI", "QUATTRO 3,0 TDI TIPTRONIC", "1,9 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "1,8 T", "1,6", "3,0 TDI", "35 TDI", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "3.0 TDI", "1,8 TFSI", "2,0 TFSI", "2,5 V6 TDI", "2.0 TDI", "2,0", "1,8", "1.9 TDI", "2,7 TDI", "2.0 TDI QUATTRO", "3,0 V6 TDI"],
      "A4 ALLROAD": ["3,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2"],
      "A4 AVANT": ["1,9 TDI", "2,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI SPORT", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,5 V6 TDI", "2,0 TDIE", "2,0", "2,0 SPORT", "2.0 TDI QUATTRO", "2,7 TDI", "2,0 TFSI", "QUATTRO 3,0 TDI TIPTRONIC", "3,0 TDI", "3.0 TDI", "3,0 V6 TDI", "2,7 V6 TDI", "2.0 TDI", "3", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC"],
      "A4 CABRIO": ["2,5 TDI", "1,8 T", "1,8"],
      "A5 CABRIO": ["2,0 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,7 TDI", "3,0 TDI"],
      "A5 COUPE": ["3.0 TDI QUATTRO", "2,0 TDI SPORT", "1,8 TFSI", "2,0 TDI", "2,7 TDI", "3.0 TDI", "3,0 TDI SPORT S-TRONIC", "3,0 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC"],
      "A5 SPORTBACK": ["2,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI SPORT S-TRONIC", "3,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,0 TDI SPORT", "2,7 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "3,0 TDI SPORT S-TRONIC", "40 TDI", "2.0 TDI", "1,8 TFSI", "3.0 TDI QUATTRO"],
      "A6": ["3,0 V6 TDI", "2,0 TDI", "2,7 V6 TDI", "3,0 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "1,9 TDI", "2,8 V6", "50 TDI", "2,5 V6 TDI", "2,4 V6", "3,0 V6", "3,2 FSI V6", "40 TDI", "3.0 TDI", "1,8", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,5 TDI", "A6 3,0 TDI QUATTRO S-TRONIC", "3", "2.0 TDI", "3.0 TDI QUATTRO", "OSOBNO"],
      "A6 ALLROAD": ["3,0 TDI", "3,0 V6 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,5 TDI", "3.0 TDI"],
      "A6 AVANT": ["2,0 TDI", "3,0 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "1,9 TDI", "3.0 TDI", "3,0 V6 TDI", "3,2 FSI V6", "2,5 V6 TDI", "2,7 V6 TDI", "2,4 V6", "2,5 TDI", "3.0 TDI QUATTRO", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "40 TDI", "1,8 T", "50 TDI"],
      "A7": ["3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "3,0 TDI", "50 TDI", "3.0 TDI"],
      "A8": ["4,2 V8", "3,0 TDI", "4,0 V8 TDI", "4,2 TDI", "OSOBNO", "3,0 V6 TDI", "50 TDI", "3.0 TDI"],
      "Q2": ["30 TDI", "1,6 TDI", "1,4 TFSI", "2,0 TDI", "OSOBNO", "1.6 TDI"],
      "Q3": ["2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI SPORT", "35 TDI", "35 TFSI", "2.0 TDI"],
      "Q5": ["Q5 2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,0 TDI", "SQ5 3,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI SPORT", "40 TDI", "3,0 TDI", "35 TDI", "2.0 TDI", "2.0 TDI QUATTRO", "50 TDI"],
      "Q7": ["3,0 V6 TDI", "3,0 TDI", "3.0 TDI", "50 TDI"],
      "Q8": ["50 TDI"],
      "TT": ["2,0 TDI", "2,0 TFSI", "2.0 TDI QUATTRO", "1,8 T", "1,8 TFSI", "3,2 V6"]
    },
    "BMW": {
      "I3": ["AUT.", "REX"],
      "M4": ["M4", "CABRIO"],
      "SERIJA 1": ["116D SPORT", "116D", "120D", "114D", "116I", "118D", "118D SPORT", "118I", "16D", "123D"],
      "SERIJA 2": ["220D", "218D", "216D", "218I"],
      "SERIJA 2 ACTIVE TOURER": ["218D", "216D", "218I", "220D"],
      "SERIJA 2 GRAN TOURER": ["218D", "216D", "220D"],
      "SERIJA 3": ["318D", "320D", "325D", "316D", "330XD", "320D SPORT", "320D M SPORT", "330D", "318I", "318D SPORT", "316I", "2.0D", "320I", "320XD", "18D"],
      "SERIJA 3 CABRIOLET": ["320CD", "320D", "330CI", "335I", "330D", "320I", "320CI"],
      "SERIJA 3 COMPACT": ["320TD", "316I"],
      "SERIJA 3 COUPE": ["320CD", "320D", "320CI", "318CI", "320I", "330CD", "330D", "335I", "330CI"],
      "SERIJA 3 GRAN TURISMO": ["320D", "318D", "1,8", "DIESEL"],
      "SERIJA 3 TOURING": ["320D", "316D", "330D", "318D", "18D", "325D", "316I", "330XD", "335I", "320I"],
      "SERIJA 4 COUPE": ["420D", "420D SPORT", "430D", "435D M SPORT", "420D M SPORT", "418D", "M4"],
      "SERIJA 4 GRAN COUPE": ["418D SPORT", "418D", "420D", "420D SPORT", "420D M SPORT", "430D", "435D M SPORT"],
      "SERIJA 5": ["520D", "530D", "530XD", "525D", "523I", "520D ALL-IN-5", "530I", "520D ALL-IN-5M", "525TDS", "518D", "520I", "535D", "525I", "525XD", "535XD", "540I", "20D", "25D"],
      "SERIJA 5 GRAN TURISMO": ["30D", "535D", "530D", "520D"],
      "SERIJA 5 TOURING": ["520D", "525D", "518D", "530D", "525XD", "530XD", "535D", "30D", "535XD", "530I"],
      "SERIJA 6": ["640D", "645CI"],
      "SERIJA 6 GRAN COUPE": ["640D"],
      "SERIJA 7": ["730D", "740D", "750LI"],
      "X1": ["20D", "XDRIVE20D", "18D", "XDRIVE18D", "SDRIVE18D", "SDRIVE20D", "SDRIVE16D", "16D", "2,0 D", "25D"],
      "X2": ["SDRIVE18D", "XDRIVE20D"],
      "X3": ["XDRIVE30D", "XDRIVE20D", "2,0 D", "XDRIVE35D", "3,0 D", "20D", "18D", "30D", "3,0 I", "SDRIVE18D", "3,0 SD", "2,0 I"],
      "X4": ["20D", "30D", "XDRIVE20D", "2.0D"],
      "X5": ["XDRIVE30D", "3,0 I", "XDRIVE40D", "XDRIVE35D", "3,0 D", "25D", "4,8 I", "30D", "M50D", "3,0 SD"],
      "X6": ["40D", "35D", "30D SPORT", "35I", "30D", "M50D", "XDRIVE30D", "XDRIVE40D"]
    }
  };
  var manufacturer = $('<select id="manufacturer"></select>');
  var model = $('<select id="model"> </select>');
  var type = $('<select id="type"> </select>');
  $.each(carsdata, function(item, key) {
    manufacturer.append('<option >' + item + '</option>');
  });
  $("#container").html(manufacturer);

  $("#manufacturer").on("change", function(e) {
    var item;
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected === "ALFA ROMEO") {
      item = carsdata[selected];
    } else {
      item = carsdata[selected];
    }
    $(model).html('');
    $.each(item, function(item, key) {
      model.append('<option>' + item + '</option>');
      $("#container").append(model);
    });
  });
  <!-- 3rd level is not working, this is my attempt: -->
  <!-- $("#model").on("change", function(e) { -->
  <!-- var item; -->
  <!-- var selected = $(this).val(); -->
  <!-- if (selected === "147") { -->
  <!-- item = carsdata[selected]; -->
  <!-- } else { -->
  <!-- item = carsdata[selected]; -->
  <!-- } -->
  <!-- $(type).html(''); -->
  <!-- $.each(item, function(item, key) { -->
  <!-- type.append('<option>' + key + '</option>'); -->
  <!-- $("#container").append(type); -->

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Just FYI, the data structure you have there is an object. JSON is a means of serialising data and isn't relevant to the issue.

Comment: Ok, dully noted. Thank you.

Comment: `$("#model").on` won't work because no element with id "model" exists when that code is executed - you haven't created it yet, and won't do until the user selects a manufacturer. It can't bind an event handler to an element which doesn't exist. What you need is "delegated event handling" - it's explained in https://api.jquery.com/on/ in the section entitled "Direct and delegated event handlers" - this enables you to declare the event handler on an element (one which definitely exists first) which is a parent of the one you really want to target , but then specify to delegate to the real target

Comment: @ADyson if you run the snippet you'll see that it works. `#type` is not working.

Comment: The delegation occurs dynamically whenever the event occurs on the parent, so it can detect newly added target elements

Comment: @Harvey you haven't understood. I never said that `model` isn't being created, I said that the "change" event you're trying to attach to the "model" element won't be attached to it. I explained why that is. Read my comment a little more carefully please :-). Rory has provided a fully worked example now anyway, so if you read that, and read the section of the jquery documentation I mentioned, then hopefully it'll become a little clearer. The bottom line of all this is - you can't attach events to elements which don't exist yet - there is a basic commonsense logic to that, I hope!

Comment: P.S. Just to extend the feedback a little, you said: `#type is not working` ...this is a misunderstanding. Type "isn't working" because it isn't being created. It isn't being created because `$("#model").on("change"` never fires, so the function to create `type` never executes. That function never executes because the "change" event never gets bound to `model`. The event never gets bound because the `model` dropdown doesn't exist yet when you try to bind the event to it. The dropdown doesn't exist yet because you don't create it until later, when the user changes the manufacturer. Make sense?

Comment: @ADyson got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern for selecting the type is the same as you are doing for manufacturer, however you need to use a delegated event handler as the `#model` element doesn't exist in the DOM when the page loads.

However you should note that the act of appending the different selects tot he DOM when an option is selected completely breaks the UI when you change the manufacturer selection multiple times after choosing a model and type. To fix that, have all the selects in the DOM initially, but hide the selects you don't need until an option is selected. Try this:

```
var $manufacturer = $('<select id="manufacturer"></select>').appendTo('#container');
var $model = $('<select id="model"></select>').appendTo('#container');
var $type = $('<select id="type"></select>').appendTo('#container');

var manuHtml = Object.keys(carsdata).map(k => `<option>${k}</option>`).join('');
$manufacturer.html('<option>Please select...</option>' + manuHtml);

$("#manufacturer").on("change", function() {
  var manufacturer = $(this).val();  
  var modelHtml = Object.keys(carsdata[manufacturer]).map(k => `<option>${k}</option>`).join('');   
  $model.html('<option>Please select...</option>' + modelHtml).show();
  $type.val('').empty().hide();
});

$(document).on('change', '#model', function() {
  var manufacturer = $('#manufacturer').val();
  var model = $(this).val();
  var typeHtml = carsdata[manufacturer][model].map(v => `<option>${v}</option>`).join('');   
  $type.html('<option>Please select...</option>' + typeHtml).show();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var carsdata = {
    "ALFA ROMEO": {
      "147": ["1,6 TS", "1,9 JTD", "1,9 JTD 16V MULTIJET", "1,9 JTD 120", "2,0 TS"],
      "156": ["1,9 JTD", "1,9 JTD 16V MULTIJET", "2,4 JTD"],
      "159": ["1,9 JTDM", "2,4 JTDM"],
      "159 SW": ["1,9 JTDM", "2,4 JTDM"],
      "166": ["2,0 TWIN SPARK 16V", "2,4 JTD", "2,0 TS"],
      "GIULIA": ["2,9 V6 BI-TURBO", "2,2 JTD", "2,2 JTDM"],
      "GIULIETTA": ["1,6 D. N. A", "2,0 D. N. A", "1,6", "2,0 TCT", "1,4 TB 16V D. N. A", "2,0", "1,6 MULTIJET", "1,4 TB"],
      "GT": ["1,9 JTD M-JET"],
      "GTV": ["2,0 TWIN SPARK 16V"],
      "MITO": ["1,6 JTDM", "1,4 T-JET", "1,4 TB", "1,3 JTDM", "1,4", "1,4 T-JET SPORT", "1,3"],
      "STELVIO": ["2,2 DIESEL", "2,0 TURBO"]
    },
    "AUDI": {
      "80": ["1,9 TDI", "2.0", "1,6"],
      "A1": ["1,6 TDI", "1,0 TFSI", "2,0 TDI", "1,4 TFSI", "1,2 TFSI", "1,6 TDI S-TRONIC", "1,4 TDI"],
      "A2": ["1,4 TDI", "1,4"],
      "A3": ["2,0 TDI", "1,6 TDI SPORT", "1,6 TDI", "1,9 TDI", "1,6", "1,6 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,0 TDI SPORT S-TRONIC", "1,8 TFSI", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "1,2 TFSI", "1,8", "1.6 TDI", "1,4 TFSI", "2,0 TDI SPORT", "35 TDI", "2,0 FSI", "1", "1,8 T", "30 TDI", "35 TFSI", "A3 LIMOUSINE 1,6 TDI S TRONIC", "1,0 TFSI"],
      "A3 CABRIO": ["1,6 TDI", "2,0 TDI", "1,9 TDI", "1,8 TFSI"],
      "A3 COUPE": ["1.6 TDI", "1,6", "2.0 TDI"],
      "A4": ["2,0 TDI SPORT", "2,0 TDI", "QUATTRO 3,0 TDI TIPTRONIC", "1,9 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "1,8 T", "1,6", "3,0 TDI", "35 TDI", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "3.0 TDI", "1,8 TFSI", "2,0 TFSI", "2,5 V6 TDI", "2.0 TDI", "2,0", "1,8", "1.9 TDI", "2,7 TDI", "2.0 TDI QUATTRO", "3,0 V6 TDI"],
      "A4 ALLROAD": ["3,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2"],
      "A4 AVANT": ["1,9 TDI", "2,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI SPORT", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,5 V6 TDI", "2,0 TDIE", "2,0", "2,0 SPORT", "2.0 TDI QUATTRO", "2,7 TDI", "2,0 TFSI", "QUATTRO 3,0 TDI TIPTRONIC", "3,0 TDI", "3.0 TDI", "3,0 V6 TDI", "2,7 V6 TDI", "2.0 TDI", "3", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC"],
      "A4 CABRIO": ["2,5 TDI", "1,8 T", "1,8"],
      "A5 CABRIO": ["2,0 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,7 TDI", "3,0 TDI"],
      "A5 COUPE": ["3.0 TDI QUATTRO", "2,0 TDI SPORT", "1,8 TFSI", "2,0 TDI", "2,7 TDI", "3.0 TDI", "3,0 TDI SPORT S-TRONIC", "3,0 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC"],
      "A5 SPORTBACK": ["2,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI SPORT S-TRONIC", "3,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,0 TDI SPORT", "2,7 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "3,0 TDI SPORT S-TRONIC", "40 TDI", "2.0 TDI", "1,8 TFSI", "3.0 TDI QUATTRO"],
      "A6": ["3,0 V6 TDI", "2,0 TDI", "2,7 V6 TDI", "3,0 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "1,9 TDI", "2,8 V6", "50 TDI", "2,5 V6 TDI", "2,4 V6", "3,0 V6", "3,2 FSI V6", "40 TDI", "3.0 TDI", "1,8", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,5 TDI", "A6 3,0 TDI QUATTRO S-TRONIC", "3", "2.0 TDI", "3.0 TDI QUATTRO", "OSOBNO"],
      "A6 ALLROAD": ["3,0 TDI", "3,0 V6 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,5 TDI", "3.0 TDI"],
      "A6 AVANT": ["2,0 TDI", "3,0 TDI", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "1,9 TDI", "3.0 TDI", "3,0 V6 TDI", "3,2 FSI V6", "2,5 V6 TDI", "2,7 V6 TDI", "2,4 V6", "2,5 TDI", "3.0 TDI QUATTRO", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "40 TDI", "1,8 T", "50 TDI"],
      "A7": ["3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "3,0 TDI", "50 TDI", "3.0 TDI"],
      "A8": ["4,2 V8", "3,0 TDI", "4,0 V8 TDI", "4,2 TDI", "OSOBNO", "3,0 V6 TDI", "50 TDI", "3.0 TDI"],
      "Q2": ["30 TDI", "1,6 TDI", "1,4 TFSI", "2,0 TDI", "OSOBNO", "1.6 TDI"],
      "Q3": ["2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI SPORT", "35 TDI", "35 TFSI", "2.0 TDI"],
      "Q5": ["Q5 2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "3,0 TDI S-TRONIC", "2,0 TDI", "SQ5 3,0 TDI", "2,0 TDI SPORT", "40 TDI", "3,0 TDI", "35 TDI", "2.0 TDI", "2.0 TDI QUATTRO", "50 TDI"],
      "Q7": ["3,0 V6 TDI", "3,0 TDI", "3.0 TDI", "50 TDI"],
      "Q8": ["50 TDI"],
      "TT": ["2,0 TDI", "2,0 TFSI", "2.0 TDI QUATTRO", "1,8 T", "1,8 TFSI", "3,2 V6"]
    },
    "BMW": {
      "I3": ["AUT.", "REX"],
      "M4": ["M4", "CABRIO"],
      "SERIJA 1": ["116D SPORT", "116D", "120D", "114D", "116I", "118D", "118D SPORT", "118I", "16D", "123D"],
      "SERIJA 2": ["220D", "218D", "216D", "218I"],
      "SERIJA 2 ACTIVE TOURER": ["218D", "216D", "218I", "220D"],
      "SERIJA 2 GRAN TOURER": ["218D", "216D", "220D"],
      "SERIJA 3": ["318D", "320D", "325D", "316D", "330XD", "320D SPORT", "320D M SPORT", "330D", "318I", "318D SPORT", "316I", "2.0D", "320I", "320XD", "18D"],
      "SERIJA 3 CABRIOLET": ["320CD", "320D", "330CI", "335I", "330D", "320I", "320CI"],
      "SERIJA 3 COMPACT": ["320TD", "316I"],
      "SERIJA 3 COUPE": ["320CD", "320D", "320CI", "318CI", "320I", "330CD", "330D", "335I", "330CI"],
      "SERIJA 3 GRAN TURISMO": ["320D", "318D", "1,8", "DIESEL"],
      "SERIJA 3 TOURING": ["320D", "316D", "330D", "318D", "18D", "325D", "316I", "330XD", "335I", "320I"],
      "SERIJA 4 COUPE": ["420D", "420D SPORT", "430D", "435D M SPORT", "420D M SPORT", "418D", "M4"],
      "SERIJA 4 GRAN COUPE": ["418D SPORT", "418D", "420D", "420D SPORT", "420D M SPORT", "430D", "435D M SPORT"],
      "SERIJA 5": ["520D", "530D", "530XD", "525D", "523I", "520D ALL-IN-5", "530I", "520D ALL-IN-5M", "525TDS", "518D", "520I", "535D", "525I", "525XD", "535XD", "540I", "20D", "25D"],
      "SERIJA 5 GRAN TURISMO": ["30D", "535D", "530D", "520D"],
      "SERIJA 5 TOURING": ["520D", "525D", "518D", "530D", "525XD", "530XD", "535D", "30D", "535XD", "530I"],
      "SERIJA 6": ["640D", "645CI"],
      "SERIJA 6 GRAN COUPE": ["640D"],
      "SERIJA 7": ["730D", "740D", "750LI"],
      "X1": ["20D", "XDRIVE20D", "18D", "XDRIVE18D", "SDRIVE18D", "SDRIVE20D", "SDRIVE16D", "16D", "2,0 D", "25D"],
      "X2": ["SDRIVE18D", "XDRIVE20D"],
      "X3": ["XDRIVE30D", "XDRIVE20D", "2,0 D", "XDRIVE35D", "3,0 D", "20D", "18D", "30D", "3,0 I", "SDRIVE18D", "3,0 SD", "2,0 I"],
      "X4": ["20D", "30D", "XDRIVE20D", "2.0D"],
      "X5": ["XDRIVE30D", "3,0 I", "XDRIVE40D", "XDRIVE35D", "3,0 D", "25D", "4,8 I", "30D", "M50D", "3,0 SD"],
      "X6": ["40D", "35D", "30D SPORT", "35I", "30D", "M50D", "XDRIVE30D", "XDRIVE40D"]
    }
  };
  
  var $manufacturer = $('<select id="manufacturer"></select>').appendTo('#container');
  var $model = $('<select id="model"></select>').appendTo('#container');
  var $type = $('<select id="type"></select>').appendTo('#container');
  
  var manuHtml = Object.keys(carsdata).map(k => `<option>${k}</option>`).join('');
  $manufacturer.html('<option>Please select...</option>' + manuHtml);

  $("#manufacturer").on("change", function() {
    var manufacturer = $(this).val();  
    var modelHtml = Object.keys(carsdata[manufacturer]).map(k => `<option>${k}</option>`).join('');   
    $model.html('<option>Please select...</option>' + modelHtml).show();
    $type.val('').empty().hide();
  });
  
  $(document).on('change', '#model', function() {
    var manufacturer = $('#manufacturer').val();
    var model = $(this).val();
    var typeHtml = carsdata[manufacturer][model].map(v => `<option>${v}</option>`).join('');   
    $type.html('<option>Please select...</option>' + typeHtml).show();
  });
});
```

```css
#model, #type {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: See the updated answer - I just made a few logic improvement tweaks to it.